Как воспроизвести видео Rutube в Фенсибокс автоплеем
Вставляю видео из Rutube в фенсибокс. Задача состоит в том, что у Rutube нет возможности запускать видео сразу, по принципу autoplay в Ютубе. Есть официальная документация, но там автоплей только для случаем если вставлять iframe. Попытался сделать следующую реализацию
$("[data-fancybox='video_gallery']").on( "click", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
         console.log('9');
          const iframe = $('.fancybox-container ').find('iframe')[0];
        
          iframe.onload = function() {
            const video =  $('.fancybox-container ').find('video'); 
            if (video) {
              video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
                video.play();
              });
            } else {
              console.error("Видеоплеер не найден внутри iframe.");
            }
          };
              
            }, 2000);
    console.log('123');
});

Ошибок нет, но видео не запускается. Может кто подскажет другие варианты, и есть ли вообще шансы?

Мне кажется вы не то делаете, iframe и нужно грузить, а в fancybox выводить не само видео, а блок или страницу, на которой будет этот iframe вставлен.

@ЕвгенийЛи , Ну суть в том чтобы сделать без вставки iframe))) фрейм перегружает страницу сильно
